# Android - It is possible get Menu View outside Menu methods?

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

It is possible get a reference to Menu view programmatically outside Menu methods?

I know that i have this, `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`and this `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, but i want get outside this.
It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I have tried this a lot of times, You will get null pointer exception if you try to get a reference out side and try to use it. Even that is not advisable. Best way is to use the menu items in `onOptionsCreatedMenu()` method and `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, maybe have to be like that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting it as an answer. Happy coding.

Comment: Others answers was the same as yors, but you was the first one Thats why i accepted yours. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes, define an instance of menu: `Menu m;` (inside your class and out side the other methods) change this variable value inside the method and use it any where you want.
PS. you have to make sure that those two methods have been executed to get the value of your View.
hope this will help.

Comment: Well, i thought about that but i would like something about getResources().getString(R.string.myString). 
But i guess that is not possible,thans anyway

Answer (score 1):

first add this at the top of the activity

```
Menu menu;
```

and this in your on create optionMenu

```
this.menu=menu
```

Now you can use your menu to access to any item 
like

```
menu.getItem(int)
```

Comment: Well, i thought about that but i would like something about getResources().getString(R.string.myString). 
But i guess that is not possible,thans anyway